# Handling scrolling in a page object model

Tags: selenium, appium

What are the best practices for scrolling to an element in a page when using page object model pattern?

If it matters, my tests are Appium tests that'll run on native iOS and Android apps.

Suppose I have this page:

```
public class LoginPage {

    private AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

    public LoginPage(AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    }

    @AndroidFindBy(className = "UIAKeyboard")
    private AndroidElement keyboard;

    @AndroidFindBy(id = "name")
    private AndroidElement nameElement;

    @AndroidFindBy(id = "password")
    private AndroidElement passwordElement;

    @AndroidFindBy(id = "login")
    private AndroidElement loginElement;

    public void scrollToLoginButton() {
        //......
    }
}
```

Is there some built in way/best practice to scroll down to the login button, aside from manually using `FluentWait`, activating a [TouchAction](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/interactions/touch/scroll/) in the `until` method every time I don't find the button to be clickable?

Comment: which driver are you using

Comment: IOSDriver and AndroidDriver, as in this: https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidDriver.html and this: https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/ios/IOSDriver.html

Comment: are you using uiautomator , exprsso which one ?

Comment: UIAutomator2 for Android, XCuiTest for iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
            "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollTextIntoView(\"login\")"));
```

you can use adroidUIAutomater class uiscrollable, see any method thats suites ui

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiScrollable

If you want to use actions class from selenium use :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
new Actions(driver).clickAndHold(e2).moveByOffset(0, -500).perform();
```

**Note:** you have to click and hold element at the bottom of the screen and scroll backwards thats why -500

or move from last element to first element:

```
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.clickAndHold(e2).moveToElement(e1);
    action.perform();
```

Comment: I know this one, it just makes less sense with a page pattern - I already have a MobileElement, I want to leverage that. I think I'll just implement the manual way so it'll fit both platforms and work with the injected MobileElement, as there doesn't seem to be the "magic bullet" I was looking for :( Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AviSasson see if the updated answer helps

Comment: Yeah, I'll use something like this, more likely I'll start from constant coordinates (say, the middle of the X axis, and 95% of the screen height) instead of clinging to an element, as I feel like most of the time you don't know what element will be down at the bottom. By the way, what's the difference between using Actions and this: https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/interactions/touch/scroll/ ?

Comment: if you check documentation the support for uiauto2 and expresso is not defined ,

Comment: Please see the updated answer added another method

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were expecting for this

```
@AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator = "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true))" +
            ".scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\"login\"))")
private AndroidElement loginElement;

public void scrollToLoginButton() {
        loginElement.click();
}
```